# Efficient Switching of I/O

Tags: switches, analog, measurement, multiplexer, ohmmeter

Reaching out as I am in the initial stages (read: crude block diagram) of circuit design for a project aiming to automate resistance checks between various connectors. We'll call these connections **A** and **B**. Each connector has 48 lines. These connectors interface with a PCB. This PCB mostly consists of an adapter from **A** to **B** but also contains passive components which I'd like to also test resistance (these have a specification defined below).

Testing for short circuits between each pin of **B** is required due to the quality control nature of this device.

As of right now, I've gone with `(6) 8x 1:1` analog switches for each connector and `(2) 8x 1:1` analog switches behind each for measurement bus selection (dependent on if the measurement is from **Connector A->B, A->A, B->B**). This seems like a bit much to me, with the number of analog switches reaching sixteen.

Resistance measurements must be taken from various lines belonging to **A** and **B**. Of note, the connections between **A** and **B** are not straight through. The measurements taken will require to not only go from each connector but between lines on each connector themselves (shown below):

`A --> B`
`A --> A`
`B --> B`

Additionally, the expected resistance measurements fall within a range of acceptable standards dependent on which pair is under test:

`less than 1.0 ohm`
`between 300-360 ohms`
`above 150k ohms`

The outputs from the `(2) 8x 1:1` analog switches will then be presented to constant current ohmmeter circuitry which in turn is fed to an ADC for usage by the main MCU.

**For this application, what is the best topology for the analog switches? Or is there another solution I am overlooking?**

I hope I've provided enough information. In the fear of none of the above making sense, I've included the crude block diagram of what I have thus far. Any suggestions for optimization would be much appreciated, I've found myself a bit blocked up.

[image: Block diagram]

Thanks!

Comment: this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum ... please ask a specific, answerable question

Comment: Start by listing your specs or expectations of test results , for interconnections, voltage , impedance, isolation ,  speed, and user interface for errors or states. Define the overall purpose then after that think of a better question

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for stopping by, I'm not looking to get down into the weeds of component specification. Only looking for any suggestions regarding topology optimization concerning the analog switches. The "measurement" section of the device is simply a constant current ohmmeter fed into an ADC. Speeds are not important for this application.

Comment: _"This seems like a bit much to me"_- Why?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Mostly due to the relative complexity and elevated BOM cost, but I suppose that comes with the territory. This is the solution I arrived at, was wondering if others would find it acceptable. Thanks!

Comment: i don't know the purpose.  It looks like a fault tester

Comment: Yes, complexity comes with the territory with this kind of testing. But perhaps you are looking at small volume manufacturing or a field test instrument that is cost sensitive. There are many ways your circuit could be optimized, depending on exactly what tests are required. What types of cables will be tested? What are the criteria for go / no go? What equipment will be used for the 'measurement' part?

Comment: By specs I means without defining how but what connections are tested. 1:1 or 1: all

Comment: Are you seriously worried that any of the 48 might short to any of the other 47 wires?  What kind of connector?  If you'd use FlatFlexible connectors, you'd really only worry about traces next to each other.

Comment: @BruceAbbott This is indeed a small volume project. As for the specification, the connectors mate directly to the DUT. The device has a certain resistance specification; here are some examples of the ranges: below 1.0 ohm (short), between 300-360 ohms, above 150k ohm (open). This automated test fixture mostly serves as a sanity check and is not required to be precise. As for the measurement portion, it will consist of a very simple constant current (~100mA) ohmmeter circuit fed into an ADC for usage with an MCU.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Connector A and Connector B don't directly connect to each other, there is a DUT in between. For the test, some are solely between pins on connector A, solely between pins on connector B, and a number of them from connector A to B.

Comment: Ok but that didn’t answer all my questions. Anyways you could simply scan with 2V and have LEDs on each pin then see a signature pattern

Comment: _"here are some examples of the ranges: below 1.0 ohm (short), between 300-360 ohms, above 150k ohm (open)."_ - so you are not just testing for 'continuity', but a particular resistance? What is the nature of the DUT?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One mux chip can only have one output enabled, so with the schematic in the question, you can't test for shorts between two pins of the A connector if they are on the same mux chip. Same for the B connector. But you can test A->B.

Measuring below 1 ohm will be difficult if the switches are in series with the resistance being measured. The lowest RdsON [8:1 mux on digikey](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NX3L4051.pdf) has resistance between 0.5 ohm typical and 0.75 ohm max. Since different switches may have different resistance, and it depends on temperature... you could use calibration, but... this is going to be annoying. Unless you relax the requirement to something like "below 2-3 ohms", in which case this switch will be fine.

If you want accurate measurements for low resistance values to spot a bad contact, you'll need 4-wire measurement. Fortunately, on the measurement side you can use any RdsON switch including the very cheap [HC/HCT4051](https://www.digikey.fr/en/products/detail/nexperia-usa-inc/74HC4051PW-118/946649), on the current injection side you can use [a bit higher RdsON switches](https://www.digikey.fr/en/products/filter/interface-analog-switches-multiplexers-demultiplexers/747?s=N4IgjCBcoCwMxyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIATAOzUwCciRYlADNXJSEW5XAGxNw1QTGrcqlABxg4rCWykN5PMK0pgYCmFPr0tPGWH5SJcgKxxz5iXWMGQI1gwlhzYKXHqvz9N9%2BZ%2BWSDXJR1xHnNqKO8AXSIABwAXKBAAZSSAJwBLADsAcxAAX2Z6EOgQVEhMXEISciopS3MHNUsQ%2BJBk1IycguKiAFouCqqsgFc60kgKGyI4kpBB71GoCamGiFiixf4kEGyAE1TBtQhElMgQCSSATwS8VIwcVB2gA) which are cheaper than the 750 mOhm ones, so in the end, it shouldn't matter much.

Assuming you only want to measure resistance on A->B, and short circuits on A->A and B->B, then you'd need 7x 8:1 current injection muxes and 7x 8:1 measurement muxes on each side.

Measuring for shorts: nested loop, for each pin, inject current, then for each pin, measure voltage. This will need a pulldown on each pin. The pin where current is injected should be near VCC, all the others should stay at 0V.

Measuring resistance: for each pin on A, inject current, set the mux on the other connector to GND, then measure voltage across the cable with the measurement muxes. Measured voltage should be below (maximum allowed resistance) x current.

The mux that connects to ground could be replaced with a shift register.

Personally I'd put the connectors on small boards connected to the main board with 0.1" headers, to change them easily when they get damaged. Or put the connector on the board, but use a male-female connector extension that gets the wear of plugging/unplugging.

Then I'd do two identical boards, one per connector. That should result in a smaller cheaper board, and again easier to replace if things go wrong. The microcontroller should be populated only one one board. They only need to be linked with supply, ground, and mux control signal, via a small mezzanine connector.